# Las sesiones no aparecen cuando hago una llamada por ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Amigos he tenido un problema con las sessiones, porque no las puedo recuperar cuando las llamo por ajax desde otro dominio (el ajax llama al dominio anterior)

yo creo las sessiones en este dominio (http://localhost/multicode/login/prueba)

y despues llamo con ajax a ese mismo dominio pero desde otro dominio (http://localhost:8084/apps/view) (Poner otro puerto es otro dominio)

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url:'http://localhost/multicode/login/prueba',
           datatype:"json",
           crossDomain: true, 
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
           dataType: 'json', 
           processData: false, 
           cache: false, 
           success : function(r){
               console.log(r)
           }
       });
```

Comment: Estas intentando llamar a tu localhost desde otro Dominio ? Intenta subiéndolo a un dominio que no sea localhost.

Comment: mi otro dominio es http://localhost:8023/apps/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En PHP, los id de sesión se pueden pasar a través de cookies o a través de parámetros en la URL. Normalmente a través de cookies porque es un método óptimo y más seguro, pero es posible a través de la URL de todos modos por si las cookies no están habilitadas ([fuente](http://php.net/manual/es/session.idpassing.php)).

Como tus sitios web están en dominios diferentes, la cookie es diferente y por eso la sesión no es la misma. Vas a tener que pasar el id de sesión como parámetro en la URL para que compartan sesión (algo que parece no se hace en la petición AJAX del código).

Otro problema que te vas a encontrar es que los datos de la sesión no van a ser los mismos en distintos servidores (incluso si has solucionado el problema de la cookie). Esto se debe a que por defecto los datos se almacenan en local y no se comparten entre distintos dominios.

Una solución para esto sería crear un id de sesión propio (con [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/es/session.customhandler.php)) y guardar los datos de la sesión en un sistema de almacenamiento "independiente" (p.e. en una base de datos) asociados a ese id de sesión.

Entonces cuando se hagan cambios o se quieran leer los datos, independientemente del dominio del que venga la petición, se escribirá/leerá la base de datos (con el id de sesión adecuado).

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren muchas formas de resolver este problema pero definitivamente la más sencilla sería usar dominios y subdominios; puedes crear una cookie que sea valida para TODOS los subdominios. Los archivos que necesitas configurar son:

- En Windows `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- En Linux:  `/etc/hosts`

De esta manera puedes fijar tus dominios como:

```
127.0.0.1  desarrollo.com
127.0.0.1  prueba.desarrollo.com
127.0.0.1  produccion.desarrollo.com
127.0.0.1  me_gusta_bailar.desarrollo.com
```

Y tus sesiónes serán compartidas entre todos estos subdominios, de esta manera puedes hacer un post desde http://desarrollo.com hacia http://prueba.desarrollo.com y tus sesiones perdurarán sin problema alguno.